# Question about total borel field?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Problem: If $\Omega$ is countable, then the total Borel field $\zeta$ is generated by the singletons, and conversely.

My question: How to prove the statement. I thought:

For the "if" part:

Since $\Omega$ is countable, than any subsets of $\Omega$ are either empty set or finite or countable. Since the countable sets is the union of the singletons.  $\zeta$ is generated by the  singletons.

For the "only if" part:

If $\zeta$ is generated by the singletons, then all the subsets of $\Omega$  are either the empty or the union of singletons, thus $\Omega$ is countable.

I do not have analysis background, so I do not know the strict mathematic proof. Can any one give some suggestion for it? Many thanks!

Some definition related :

1. The definition of Borel field:

A nonempty collection $A$ of subsets of $\Omega$

(1)$E\in A\Longrightarrow E^{c}\in A$

(2)$E_j\in A; 1\leq j<\infty; \Longrightarrow \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j\in A$

2. The defintion of total Borel field:

The collection $\zeta$ of all subset of $\Omega$ is a Borel Field , called the total borel field.

3.the Borel Field generated by $\zeta$:

Given any nonempty collection $\zeta$ of sets, there is a minimal Borel Field containing it, which is just the intersection of all Borel Field, called the Borel Field generated by $\zeta$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an ancient version of a $\sigma$-algebra.

What you're looking for is the fact that there is a Borel Field $\mathcal{A}$ which consists of all the countable subsets of $\Omega$ that are either countable or have countable complement (in fact, this particular Borel Field is a $\sigma$-algebra). You can simply check that each of your two axioms of a Borel Field are satisfied.

Clearly, $\mathcal{A}$ contains all the singletons, so the minimal Borel Field generated by the singletons is smaller than $\mathcal{A}$, no matter $\Omega$. Hence, if the Field generated by the singletons is $\zeta,$ then $\zeta\subseteq \mathcal{A},$ but, by definition of the Total Borel Field (the power set of $\Omega$ as it is known in nowadays) we also have $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \zeta$. Hence, $\mathcal{A}=\zeta$.

Now, we need to prove that if $\mathcal{A}$ is the power set of $\Omega,$ then $\Omega$ is countable. In order to prove this, we need to show that if $\Omega$ is uncountable, then there exists an uncountable $U\subseteq \Omega$ such that $\Omega\setminus U$ is also uncountable. I'm not actually sure how to prove this without the continuum hypothesis. If you do have the continuum hypothesis, simply pick an injection $f:[0,1]\to \Omega$ and let $U=f([0,1/2])$.